# Why don’t methods focus on constructing expected distributions and solving the integrals

Tags: normal-distribution, kelly-criterion, expected-value, position-sizing, bayes-theory

Everyone knows assumptions of normality etc are bad and that the expected distributions of financial quantities (such as returns) change depending on the circumstances.

We know that we can compute the asymptotic optimal EV position sizing by solving the integral associated with a distribution (generalized Kelly). So why doesn’t the literature, firms, etc. focus on systematic data-driven Bayesian updates of expected probability distributions in various circumstances, and then just applying the optimal position sizing.

Surely this isn’t a novel idea. Is there severe computational issues or something I’m missing.

Comment: Hi: It's an interesting question but I'm not clear on how assuming some other distribution would help ?

Comment: Can you write down the "integral associated with a distribution in generalized Kelly formula" that you refer to? Or remind me what it says.

Comment: @nbbo2 see the last portion of this article, which has the integrals and code: https://quantdare.com/kelly-criterion/